# laravel autoloading a Helper with composer

Tags: php, laravel-4

Laravel 4.x
Hi I'm learning about Helpers. i have a Helper (helpers.php) that I want to load so my function in the View will be able to process the data.

My composer.json

```
...
},
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "app/commands",
            "app/controllers",
            "app/models",
            "app/database/migrations",
            "app/database/seeds",
            "app/tests/TestCase.php"
        ],
        "files" : [
            "app/helpers.php"
        ]
    },
...
```

but by running :  `composer dump-autoload --optimize`
I have no error but my view doesn't process the data

View

```
 <img src="foo($photo->user->name) }}.jpg" alt="" >
```

My helpers.php

```
function foo($email)
{
    //process some data here that will return the name
    return "john";

}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you don't get any errors about a non-existant function, I think your might be just wrong.

You have this:

```
<img src="foo($photo->user->name) }}.jpg" alt="" >
```

But should have this:

```
<img src="{{ foo($photo->user->name) }}.jpg" alt="" >
```

Answer (score 3):

Create a `classes` directory in your `app/`

Modify `app/start/global.php` as

```
ClassLoader::addDirectories(array(
  app_path().'/commands',
  app_path().'/controllers',
  app_path().'/models',
  app_path().'/database/seeds',
  app_path().'/classes', //add this
));
```

Create your `Helpers.php` file in new created `classes` directory.

```
<?php
class Helpers {
    public static function myCoolFunction() {
        return "so cool";
    }
}
```

Sometimes you may need to run `composer dump-autoload`.

Here you go: `Helpers::myCoolFunction();`

## Addition

Also another quick way (there several ways actually), but not recommend, put your function to `boostrap/start.php`. You can call wherever you want.

Comment: thks Metude 4 this answer!

Comment: You're welcome, is there another reason not to check as anwer?

Comment: Melude. I voted two hours ago. There is somebody else that had voted before me on your answer.